# UI doesn't update

Tags: angular

I need to improve our site. On the previous code, that is commented, there was one call for every id to server. I made (on the un-commented code) one call to server with all needed Ids. it seems that the speed is better, but the status in the UI is not updated.

Any idea?

```js
getStatuses(){

const ids = []
this.requests.forEach(r=>{
  ids.push(r.id)
})
const result =  this.executorService.getExecutionsStatusses(ids)
this.requests.forEach(r=> {
  result.pipe(
    tap(eStatus => this.statuses[r.id] = eStatus[r.id]),
    repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(5000))),
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(result => this.statuses[r.id] = result);
})
//this.requests.forEach(r => {
//  //refresh execution status each 5 seconds till finished
//  this.executorService.getExecutionStatus(r.id).pipe(
//    //update the statuses data structure with ExecutionStatus
//    tap(eStatus => this.statuses[r.id] = eStatus),
//    //keep polling until complete
//    repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(5000))),
//    filter(es =>  ["skipped", "passed", "failed", "aborted"].includes(es.status)),
//    take(1)
//    ).subscribe(result => this.statuses[r.id] = result);
// });
```

I provide also the HTML of the status:

```html
          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <span class="status status-{{statuses[element.id]?.status}}"> {{statuses[element.id]?.status}}</span>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
```

This is when it calls(on rising of page):

```
   ngOnInit() {
   for (const field of ["id", "user", "testplan", "test", "setup", 
  "status"]){ //filter runs on this columns
   this.filters[field] = new FormControl("")
    }

  let initial_filter = new RequestsFilter()
  initial_filter.page=this.curr_page
  initial_filter.pageSize=this.PAGE_SIZE
  this.fetchData(initial_filter)
}

 fetchData(filter: RequestsFilter) {
  this.executorService.getdRequestsForPage(filter).subscribe(r => {
  this.requests = r.sort((a, b) => (b.id - a.id))
  this.build_data()
  this.getStatuses();
 })
```

}

Comment: Please provide the HTML file. I can't say where is the data coming from.

Comment: how the statuses in the template is linked to getStatuses in the component?

Comment: Now more clear?